# How to programmatically add UIView in a scrollview in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiscrollview

I used the below codes

```
CGRect scrollserviceViewFrame1 = CGRectMake(60,610, 650, 150);
    //CGRect scrollViewFrame =[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    //UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    UIScrollView *servicescrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollserviceViewFrame1];
    [self.view addSubview:servicescrollView1];
    //scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];  
    [servicescrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [servicescrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    //scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
    servicescrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;     // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
    servicescrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
    servicescrollView1.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    [servicescrollView1 setContentSize: CGSizeMake(1050, 100)]; 
    //scrollView.delegate = self;
    servicescrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
    servicescrollView1.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [servicescrollView1 scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(servicescrollView1.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"  scroll view width :%i ",servicescrollView1.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"scroll view height :%i ",self.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"self view width :%i",self.view.frame.size.width);


    CGRect CGRectZero = CGRectMake(60,710,200, 100);    
    UIView* myserviceView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    myserviceView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [servicescrollView1 addSubview:myserviceView1];
    [myserviceView1 release];


    [servicescrollView1 release];
```

The scroll view is created , butcannot add the UIVIew to scrollview...

Any suggestions for solving this query???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take care to format your questions nicely. You can read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to get an idea of what is considered a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Near the bottom of your code where you create `myserviceView1`, you (attempt to) ***reset*** a constant (`CGRectZero`).

And then when you create your `myserviceView1` UIView, you're giving it a frame size of `{0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: ...Thanks....I changed near the bottom  code in to below       CGRect CGRectZero1 = CGRectMake(60,710,200, 100); 
 UIView* myserviceView1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero1];
 myserviceView1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
 [servicescrollView1 addSubview:myserviceView1];
 [myserviceView1 release];       But the problem is not resolved...Any more suggestions????   Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your original question to show this updated code.  And change that *confusing* variable name from `CGRectZero1` to something more sensible, like `myServiceViewFrame`.